# pandas timeseries plot xticks second-level granularity

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have some pandas dataframes with time series data of about 20 minutes duration. When I call plot on them, some of the plots show the x-ticks as hh:mm:ss while some of them show up as hh:mm.

This causes confusion when comparing the output graphs. How can I force the hh:mm ones to have the second-level granularity as the others?

Per request from first commenter, here is a dataframe that produces hh:mm:ss formatted plot

```
  In [68]:dfd
  Out[68]:
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  DatetimeIndex: 1193 entries, 2013-05-30 00:00:00 to 2013-05-30 00:19:59
  Data columns:
  disk_util    1193  non-null values
  dtypes: float64(1)

  In [69]:
  dfd.plot()  # this gives hh:mm:ss plot
```

But this one gives hh:mm formatted plot:

```
    In [63]: dfn
    Out[63]:
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    DatetimeIndex: 1197 entries, 2013-05-30 00:00:00 to 2013-05-30 00:19:56
    Data columns:
    net_util    1197  non-null values
    dtypes: float64(1)

    In [64]: dfn.plot()
```

Comment: Post some example code for us to try.

Comment: Thanks! I read the data out of csv files, not from code. See http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/changhiskhan/talks/master/pydata2012/pandas_timeseries.ipynb Out[20] for a plot that show up xticks in hh:mm format. How do we make it show up second level granularity?

Comment: Posting two dataframes values for comparison.

Comment: I followed that link and could not easily identify which data I should copy. (For example, I only see the first 20 results of ``filled``, the data plotted in Out[20].) The DataFrame descriptions you posted don't help us try out your code. Please post the data or, better yet, a small subset that reproduces your problem. If it's too long, use [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I plot a sub range of the data frame which was giving hh:mm format x-scale ticks, I see it gives hh:mm:ss formatted x-ticks. This suggests pandas is optimizing the display of the ticks when a certain size is exceeded.

I also noticed above that the disk_util dataframe above had 1193 samples but the time spanned 2013-05-30 00:00:00 to 2013-05-30 00:19:59, which implies there were some timestamps when there was no readings. This imperfection probably resulted in pandas not opitmizing the display to hh:mm format.

Whereas the net_util    1197  non-null values had timespan 2013-05-30 00:00:00 to 2013-05-30 00:19:56 which implies no missing samples, and pandas optimized the display to hh:mm.

When I artificially deleted a sample from the dataframe (df=df.drop(20)), it introduces a missing sample, and the graph comes in hh:mm:ss format. So my issue is now solved.